# Apache Netbeans not compiling

Tags: installation, netbeans, directory, compilation

I am trying to compile a program I wrote for a college course 10 years ago.
Recently loaded Apached Netbeans, but cannot get program to compile.

My notes for setup from back then are not helpful.
Guidance please? Do I need all files in same directory?

Here is what I have:

My project resides C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Flash Drive contents\IS251-Fall\Java course programs\GuessingGame

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
Java: 14.0.2; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.0.2+12-46
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 14.0.2+12-46
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0
Cache directory: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.0

System variable
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I have also tried to open as a NEW project with existing sources as a Java Web App. It says it uses ANT. I'm not sure what this is. ???
Trying to setup a server. Guessing I will look at Tomcat. ???

Comment: I downloaded Tomcat and setup a server. 
Tried to compile. Getting different errors. 
HELP!
Going to try installing JDK 15. 
error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 14
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: Ok, that was it! 
Compiled and able to run using Tomcat.